# Django/mysql intermidiate table not inserting data

Tags: python, mysql, django, many-to-many

I have this 3 tables M2M relation between Notification and user and in that intermediate table ive inserted an value from history table. when i generate content in the history table the intermediate table (notification_user) is allways empty.
Another question, the value that i want in the notification_user table is the "status" from the history table, and not the id, any suggestion about that?

Models.py

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    application = models.ManyToManyField('Products.Application')
    notificationType = models.ForeignKey(NotificationType)
    url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.ManyToManyField('Geolocations.Country', null=True, blank=True)
    browser = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    ip = models.IPAddressField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Notification_User')

class History(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ip = models.IPAddressField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    browser = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    os = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    notification = models.ForeignKey(Notification)

class Notification_User(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    notification = models.ForeignKey(Notification)
    status = models.ForeignKey(History, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py (method where i insert the data into history table)

```
notifications = Notification.objects.filter(**condition).\
    exclude(history__user_id__userid=userid, history__status=1).\
    order_by('notificationType__priority')

for n in notifications:
    nid = n.id
    user = User(userid=userid, username=username)
    user.save()
    history = {'user': user,
               'status': " ",
               'ip': ip,
               'country': country,
               'city': city,
               'browser': k[1],
               'os': k[0],
               'notification_id': nid
    }
    History.objects.create(**history)
```

Comment: Can you provide code where you inserting data?

Comment: yes, updated in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot insert data because your intermediate table contains more than 2 foreign keys and cannot perform the matching. From documentation:

> Your intermediate model must contain one - and only one - foreign key
>   to the source model (this would be Group in our example), or you must
>   explicitly specify the foreign keys Django should use for the
>   relationship using ManyToManyField.through_fields. If you have more
>   than one foreign key and through_fields is not specified, a validation
>   error will be raised. A similar restriction applies to the foreign key
>   to the target model (this would be Person in our example).

As stated here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields, you can use **through_fields**. The example matches your case:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership', through_fields=('group', 'person'))

class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    inviter = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="membership_invites")
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

**Updated answer:**

Also, to create m2m relationship in your view.py:

```
Notification_User.objects.create(user = UserObject, notification = NotificationObject)
```

Comment: ive added user = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Notification_User',through_fields=('notification','user')) but its the same, the table continues empty

Comment: And the through_fields is useless here, because my foreign keys are all from different tables. in that example he has 2 foreign keys from the same table(Person)

Comment: Yes the intermediate table is empty because you aren't creating any m2m relations here, just history objects. You must create Notification_User objects like: `n = Notification_User.objects.create(user =UserObject, notification =NotificationObject)`

Comment: Worked, can update your answer to close the question